# Подключение модуля

Tags: node.js

Сразу скажу, что я только начинаю изучать Node js и этот вопрос легкий, я уверен.

Короче, нужно подключить файл из другого файла.

Основной (откуда нужно подключать) лежит по пути

```
C:\Users\someuser\somefolder\somefoldertwo\somefolderthree\somefolderfo\mainfile.js
```

Тот, который нужно подключать:

```
C:\Users\someuser\somefolder\somefoldertwo\somefolderthree\mymodule.js
```

Как его подключить через requre?

Comment: Если вам дам исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

```
require("./../mymodule.js");
```